prove that $x^{51}$ is congruent to $1\bmod(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)$
Consider $m(x)=x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ as used in AES. Next define the field $GL(2^8)=\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/m(x)$.
How might I go about showing that $x^{51} \equiv1\bmod(m(x))$.
I've tried factoring into exponents of powers of 2 (i.e. $x^{51}=x^{32}x^{16}x^2x^1$) and determining each as a square of another. Yet I am left with terms that do not cancel out in the final product. Am presently combing over my working for errors but cannot see anything glaring.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

I'd recommend using the Euclidean algorithm or trying to use polynomial divison to show that $m(x)$ divides $x^{51}-1$.

Squaring an element in $GF(2^n)$ (and indeed $p$-th-powering an element in $GF(p^n)$ is very easy. Just double the individual monomial powers.

So you have $x^8=x^4+x^3+x+1$, $x^{16}=x^8+x^6+x^2+1=x^6+x^4+x^3+x^2+x$ and so on.

We must have $x^{2^8-1}=1$ and $2^8-1=255=5\times\color{blue}{51},$ but I don’t know if that helps

With usual misgivings I'm promoting my comment to an answer.

You seem to be aware of the technique of the square-and-multiply algorithm, which is, indeed, essential here. My suggestion is the following trick that should still save some of the remaining labor.
You have already calculated the remainder of $x^{16}$ so one simple step gives you the remainder of $x^{17}$. I denote that remainder by $y$. Should it happen that $y=1$, then the same holds for the remainder of $x^{51}=y^3$. If that's not the case, my advice would be to next calculate
$$
y^2+y+1.
$$
That is, one more squaring (followed by reduction).
The point is that if $y\neq1$, then
$$
y^2+y+1=\frac{y^3-1}{y-1}=\frac{x^{51}-1}{x^{17}-1}.
$$
This is clearly equal to zero if and only if $x^{51}=1$, but checking that $y$ is a root of that quadratic may be a little bit easier.

Basically I'm using the fact that $51=3\cdot17$. Here $17$ is conveniently close to a power of two, and $3$ is small.

For brevity a comma-separated list of numbers represents the sum of $x$ raised to the powers of those numbers.
$$x^8=4,3,1,0$$
$$x^9=5,4,2,1$$
$$x^{10}=6,5,3,2$$
$$x^{12}=8,7,5,4=7,5,3,1,0$$
$$x^{14}=9,7,5,3,2=7,4,3,1$$
$$x^{24}=14,10,6,2,0=7,5,4,1,0$$
$$x^{48}=14,10,8,2,0=7,6,5,3$$
$$x^{51}=10,9,8,6=0,$$

Was this easier than computing $x^{16}$ and $x^{32}$ (which OP suggested)?

@J.W.Tanner Actually, yes.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $p(x) = x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0 \in A[x]$.  The $A$ algebra $A[x]/(p(x))$ is free with basis $1$, $x$, $\ldots$, $x^{n-1}$ isomorphic to the $A$-algebra $A[M]$ where $M$ is the $n\times n$ companion matrix of the polynomial $p(x)$
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 0& 0& 0&\ldots& -a_0\\
                      1& 0& 0& \ldots& -a_1\\
                      0& 1& 0& \ldots& -a_2\\
                      \ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots &\ldots\\
                       0&0&\ldots &1 & -a_{n-1}
 \end{pmatrix}$$
with $x\mapsto M$.  Note that for an element $N$ of $A[M]$ we'll have $N = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k M^k$, where $(c_0, \ldots, c_{n-1})$ is the first column of $N$.
S0, with $p(x) = x^8 + x^4+x^3+x+1 \in \mathbb{Z}/2[x]$, we can automatize the calculations, since matrix calculations are standard. We'll skip the  details; raising the matrix $M$ to powers should use perhaps the powers of $2$ "trick" ( nobody multiplies by  successively adding , and so nobody should raise to power by successively multiplying ).
